# useContext and useReducer not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a page where a user is able to add a product from shop page to cart using `useContext` and `useReducer`. They can update how much quantity they want of a product using the quantity counter. This works!

I have another page where user clicks on a product for more information and they can decide to add to basket with a quantity counter there too. Adding to the basket from this page works, but when I try to use `useContext` for the counter it does not.

I want to be able to use `useContext` so that when a user changes the quantity on the product page, it will update on the cart page.

**UseContext.js (Context page)**

```js
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'
import { createContext } from 'react'

// this is what is exported to the children page and this is where the states will be 'pulled from'
export const AppContext = createContext()

export const Context = (props) => {
    // this uses useReducer which holds the states like useState except that it the state can be used for different things e.g. if we want to add or delete from the state
    // it returns the state and dispatch, we put the action in the dispatch
    // reducer accepts the current state and the action

    // Different button functions on the cart page
    const reducer = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "ADD":
                // if statement if array of state is empty 
                // filter state and it item is available add to the new state
                const tempState = state.filter((item) => action.payload.id === item.id);
                if (tempState.length > 0) {
                    return state
                }
                // spread the state with the action that has been called
                else {
                    return [...state, action.payload]
                }
            case "PLUS":
                const countPlus = state.map((item) => {
                    // if item id has the same id as the action that is being sent, which means that the item is available
                    if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
                        // if item is available then increase quantity of 1
                        return { ...item, quantity: Math.min(10, item.quantity + 1) };
                    } else {
                        return item
                    }
                })
                return countPlus
            case "MINUS":
                const countMinus = state.map((item) => {
                    if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
                        return { ...item, quantity: Math.min(0, item.quantity - 1) };
                    } else {
                        return item
                    }
                })
                return countMinus
            case "REMOVE":
                const cartRemove = state.filter((item) =>
                    // filter out the items that have been clicked on with a matching id 
                    item.id !== action.payload.id
                )
                return cartRemove
            default:
                return state
        }
    }

 
    
// function to get cart into local storage
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, [], () => {
    const localCartData = localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
    return localCartData ? JSON.parse(localCartData) : []
})


// function to save to local storage
const information = { state, dispatch }
// set the local storage of the keyvalue pair e.g. savedItems will be the key and then the savedState will be the value 
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(state))
}, [state]);

// set local storage with a time out after  24 hours
const twentyFourHours = 24 * 60 * 60
setTimeout(() => localStorage.removeItem('cartItems'), twentyFourHours * 1000);


return (

    <AppContext.Provider
        value={information}>
        {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
)
}
```

**Cart.js (This is the page where it is working)**

```js
import { useContext } from "react"
import {AppContext } from "../Context/Context"

function Cart() {
  const CartState = useContext(AppContext);
  const state = CartState.state;
  const dispatch = CartState.dispatch;


  const total = state.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    return accumulator + currentValue.price * currentValue.quantity 
  }
    , 0)




  return (
    <div>
      {state.length === 0 ?
        (<h1>Your cart is empty </h1>) :


        state.map((item, index) => {
          return (
          
            <div className='addCard' key={index}>
              <img src={item.api_featured_image} alt={item.brand + item.product_type}></img>
              {/* To display the brand name with as sentence case */}
              <p>{item?.brand ? item.brand.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.brand.slice(1).toLowerCase() : item.brand} {item?.name ? item.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.name.slice(1).toLowerCase() : item.name}</p>
              <p>{item?.product_type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.product_type.slice(1).toLowerCase()}</p>
              <p>£{(item?.price === '0.0')
                ? item.price = '8.50'
                : Number(item.price).toFixed(2)}</p>
              <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "PLUS", payload: item })}>
                +
              </button>
              <p>{item.quantity}</p>
              <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "MINUS", payload: item })}>
                -
              </button>
              <p>£{(item.price * item.quantity).toFixed(2)}</p>
              <button onClick={() => {console.log(item.id);dispatch({ type: "REMOVE", payload: item })}}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6">
                  <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M14.74 9l-.346 9m-4.788 0L9.26 9m9.968-3.21c.342.052.682.107 1.022.166m-1.022-.165L18.16 19.673a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244 2.077H8.084a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244-2.077L4.772 5.79m14.456 0a48.108 48.108 0 00-3.478-.397m-12 .562c.34-.059.68-.114 1.022-.165m0 0a48.11 48.11 0 013.478-.397m7.5 0v-.916c0-1.18-.91-2.164-2.09-2.201a51.964 51.964 0 00-3.32 0c-1.18.037-2.09 1.022-2.09 2.201v.916m7.5 0a48.667 48.667 0 00-7.5 0" />
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
      {state.length > 0 && (
      < h1 > Total:£{total.toFixed(2)}</h1>
      )}
    </div >

  )
}

export default Cart
```

**Product.js (This is when the add to cart context is working but not incrementing quantity on the products page to show the change on the cart page)**

```js
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import GetSingleProduct from '../Hooks/getSingleProduct'
import { AppContext } from '../Context/Context'
import '../Assets/Styles/Product.css'

function Product() {
  // able to use useParams to direct to the page with the id of the product that has been clicked
  const { id } = useParams()
  const { singleProduct, isLoading, error } = GetSingleProduct(`https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products/${id}.json`)
  const [clickedColour, setClickedColour] = useState([])

  // const disablePlusBtn = () => {
  //   singleProduct.quantity === 10 || singleProduct.quantity === 0 ?
  //     <button className='cursor-not-allowed'>+</button> && setDisableBtn(true)
  //     : <button onClick={handleIncrement}>+</button>
  // }


  // useContext for the add to cart 
  const Cartstate = useContext(AppContext)
  const dispatch = Cartstate.dispatch;

  const handleColour = (index) => {
    setClickedColour(prevstate =>
    ({
      ...prevstate, [index] // copies prev state
        : !prevstate[index]
    }))
    console.log(setClickedColour)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='routeTaken'>
        <ol>
          <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/shop'>Shop</Link></li>
          <li>Current page</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div className='productInfo'>
        {error && <div>{error}</div>}
        {isLoading ?
          (<div>Loading...</div>) :
          <div id={singleProduct.id}>
            <img src={singleProduct.api_featured_image} alt={singleProduct.product_type}></img>
            <p>{singleProduct?.product_type ? singleProduct.product_type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + singleProduct.product_type.slice(1).toLowerCase().split('_').join(' ') : singleProduct.product_type}</p>

            <h1>{singleProduct?.brand ? singleProduct.brand.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + singleProduct.brand.slice(1).toLowerCase() : singleProduct.brand} {singleProduct?.name ? singleProduct.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + singleProduct.name.slice(1).toLowerCase() : singleProduct.name}</h1>
            <h2> £{singleProduct.price === '0.0' || singleProduct.price === null ? '8.50' : Number(singleProduct.price).toFixed(2)}</h2>
            <h3>{singleProduct.description}</h3>
            {/* {singleProduct.map(colour => 
            <h1>{colour.product_colors}</h1>)} */}
            <div className="colourList grid grid-cols-4">
              {singleProduct.product_colors?.map((colour, index) => {
                return (
                  <button onClick={() => handleColour(index)} className='colourItem' key={index} style={{ backgroundColor: colour.hex_value }}>
                    {colour.hex_value}
                    {clickedColour[index] ?
                      (<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6">
                        <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M4.5 12.75l6 6 9-13.5" />
                      </svg>
                      ) : (null)}
                  </button>
                )
              })}
            </div>
            <div className='counter'>
                <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'PLUS', payload: singleProduct })}>
                  +
                </button>
                <p>{singleProduct.quantity}</p>
              </div>
              <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'ADD', payload: singleProduct })}>Add to basket</button>
            </div>
        }
          </div >
    </>
      )
}

      export default Product
```

I want to be able to share the count on the products and cart page, even if it is changed on different pages!
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `<Context>` a parent of both product and cart?

Comment: Yes, AppContext is called in both, if that is what you meant?

Comment: Not the same thing. Is `AppContext` a parent of both `Product` and `Cart`? I.e. `<AppContext><Product /><Cart /></AppContext>`.

Comment: This is what I have in my index.js.   
<React.StrictMode>
    <Context>
      <App />
    </Context>
  </React.StrictMode>
In that case then yes they both are.

Comment: Just checking, but I assume that <Context> is either a wrapper for <AppContext> or should be <AppContext>, yes?

Comment: <Context> is what the js file is called and AppContext is what I call the context file on the children pages. In 2 other pages, it works with no problems. So I don't think it is down to how I have wrapped or called them unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, yes I see that now.

Comment: Is it the action `PLUSPRODUCT` that is not working? If so, your reducer doesn't seem to have a case for this action type.

Comment: Sorry that was an older version, edited the changes to how it should be. However still not functioning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254310/discussion-between-stuart-nichols-and-lucype9297).